# Rollout approach for centOS/RHEL linux servers to achieve centralised authentication through AD

Tags: active-directory, centos6, centos5, centos7, chef

We have 3 environments testing develop and production each having more than 40 Linux servers. Need to establish centralized authentication through AD for all these environment.

Which is the best approach can I used to achieve this?

AD- Windows server 2008
Linux versions - CentOS 6.5/6.5/5.10/5.11/7.01

Can you guide is it possible to use the chef server to roll out centralized authentication through AD for Linux servers to leverage the automation.

Any high level steps to achieve?